# PYTHON - After first tab, remove portions of lines within a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I'm trying to remove portions of lines within a text file.
Need to know the best way to remove all characters remaining on lines within a text file after and including the first tab.

Before :

10

```
.10.10.0    10.10.10.255    24  123 ABC GOOD be (XXXX-XXX-X-BLK1)   USA         
30.30.30.0  30.30.30.255    24  456 DEF OK NOT be (XXXX-XXX-X-BLK2) USA
```

After :

```
10.10.10.0
30.30.30.0
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open("filename.txt","r")
for line in f:
    print(line.split("\t")[0])
```

So first you open the file you want to read. You start reading it line by line. For each line, split the line with the **\t** character which stands for tab and than print the first item on the list.(split function returns a list). For performance reasons there are better ways, for example reading the line char by char but for beginner level 3 lines of code is enough I guess.

Comment: Thank you atayenel. That worked almost perfectly.  Now if I can get it to do that without removing the carriage return at the end of each line, i'll be in business.

Comment: the char for carriage return is **\r**. you can add it to your string if you want and store it in a variable. Be warned that: printing out a string with a carriage return will cause that string to be erased when a new string is printed.